# How to perform a post request using a file content as body in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

**What I want to:**

1. I want to read a parquet file in a Data Lake (gen2)
2. And I will make some changes on the dataset(i.e. firstly column transforming (like string to int). Then change some values for some samples. (like change "Star_Count" column with "200" for sample "where primary_key == 500" ) )
3. Then I want to pass the data to an endpoint. So I need to do **post request** using the **dataset as** **body**.

**What can I do:**

- I have connected to Data Lake and have read parquet file. (i.e. I can make Copy activity on Data Lake)
- I have created a Post Web API in Data Factory and I can make some
  mock Post request. (with empty body)

**What is the question:**

- My first question is how can I pass the dataset (after the first and second steps (in What I want to) ) to
  post request as body?
- And the second question is what is the best way to making changes on
  reading data to pass post request as body? (I mean the second step)

By the way my data factory is v2.

Comment: What kind of changes? Data Factory as a data transformation tool is not very mature. The expression language is basically a bunch of nested functions with no validation. You'd need to load your parquet into a variable then transform the variable with an undebuggable expression then use that variable in the post area. You might want to look into mapping data flows. Is it worth storing the transformed data in the data lake also? That would probably be easier as you could use ADF to call an external process to transform then load it and post it off.

Comment: Firstly transforming then storing transformed data in the data lake is a possibility but the question is same how can I give the data to post method as body? You are saying load parquet in a variable but how can I do it? I think I can not do it using with Data Factory UI. Do I have to do it (creating pipeline to read- transform - set a variable - give it to body of post method) with .NET SDK?

Comment: I haven't done it before but first thing that comes to mind is to, ironically, use the REST API to pull data out of the datalake, capture the body in a variable, transform it, then post it off again. I'd need to experiment - there is probably a better way. Are you just selecting one parquet file at a time? What is the transform doing?

Comment: Yes I know the way that you say but I have to use it with Data Factory.

Comment: OK well what transformation are you doing, and how are you deciding which file to process, and are you processing one at a time?